# Running PHP from command line

Tags: php, command-line, cron, ffmpeg

I am trying to manage a queue of files waiting to be processed by ffmpeg. A page is run using CRON that runs through a database of files waiting to be processed. The page then builds the commands and sends them to the command line using `exec()`.

However, when the PHP page is run from the command line or CRON, it runs the `exec()` OK, but does not return to the PHP page to continue updating the database and other functions.

Example:

```
<?php
$cmd = "ffmpeg inpupt.mpg output.m4v";

exec($cmd . ' 2>&1', $output, $return);

//Page continues...but not executed
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE.....");
?>
```

When this page is run from the command line, the command is run using `exec()` but then the rest of the page is not executed. I think the problem may be that I am running a command using `exec()` in a page run from the command line.

**Is it possible to run a PHP page in full from the command line which includes `exec()`?**

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Comment: `exec()` time should not count towards it on U*ix, but try to raise the `set_time_limit()` for your script.

Comment: @mario - thanks, I have already tried this. No luck unfortunately. The `exec()` output is visible in the command line, then just stops and does not return to the PHP page.

Comment: No idea then. But try `system()` instead of `exec()`. In PHP both behave similar, but actually use different system calls (in case a shell failure result causes your script termination).

Comment: You're using a  linux/unix based platform, right?

Comment: @Salman, yeah. I think I've got it now. I'm using CURL as suggested below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using CURL instead?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Works pefectly.. dont know why I was trying to run it directly in the cmd line..!

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an article about [Running a Background Process from PHP on Linux](http://911-need-code-help.blogspot.com/2010/04/running-background-process-in-php.html) some time ago:

```
<?php system( 'sh test.sh >/dev/null &' ); ?>
```

Notice the `&` operator at the end. This starts a process that returns control to the shell immediately AND CONTINUES TO RUN in the background.

More examples:

```
<!--
    saving standard output to a file
    very important when your process runs in background
    as this is the only way the process can error/success
-->
<?php system( 'sh test.sh >test-out.txt &' ); ?>
<!--
    saving standard output and standard error to files
    same as above, most programs log errors to standard error hence its better to capture both
-->
<?php system( 'sh test.sh >test-out.txt 2>test-err.txt &' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unsure but probably thats due to the shell constraints of cron processes if it works as a web page then use it as a web page, setup a cron job that calls `wget wherever_your_page_is` and it will be called via your web server and should mimic your tests.

Comment: Thank you - this is a nice idea. I will try now.